# How to validate an API key in Google cloud endpoints v2

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am new to Google cloud endpoints especially V2, I see it as an important layer for making service based applications .
From the documentations I observed they provided options for using endpoints framework and then open api .Now when I use the frameworks with api key required and then generate the openapi.json .i can't seem to get any error when I make a request without the API key .I wonder why it is so when I have marked my class as API key required .Am I to provide the validation logic myself ?.
This is the configuration for validating all methods withing the api.

```
@Api(name = "testapi",
    version = "v1",
    apiKeyRequired = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE,
    scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
    clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
```

)

And then to generate the openapi.json file this is the pom config , Although i'm still trying to grasp how to configure it in such a way i wont need to enter my service classes

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>GetSwaggerDoc</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>GetSwaggerDoc</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                        <mainClass>com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>get-swagger-doc</argument>
                            <argument>--hostname=test-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</argument>
                            <argument>--war=target/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
                            <argument>com.rareatom.test.services.TestApi</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
                            <artifactId>endpoints-framework-tools</artifactId>
                            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
                            <version>1.9.30</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>`
```

when i run `mvn exec:java -DGetSwaggerDoc`
This is generated

```html
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
 "info": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "title": "test-api.endpoints.test-test-160113.cloud.goog"
 },
 "host": "test-api.endpoints.test-test-160113.cloud.goog",
 "basePath": "/_ah/api",
 "schemes": [
  "https"
 ],
 "consumes": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "produces": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "paths": {
  "/testapi/v1/test": {
   "post": {
    "operationId": "TestapiTest",
    "parameters": [ ],
    "responses": {
     "200": {
      "description": "A successful response",
      "schema": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/Response"
      }
     }
    },
    "security": [
     {
      "google_id_token": [ ]
     },
     {
      "google_id_token_https": [ ]
     },
     {
      "api_key": [ ]
     }
    ],
    "x-security": [
     {
      "google_id_token": {
       "audiences": [
        "AIzaSyAsnv2yeF6003txjfBVrZrlUe8jvfUJAtE"
       ]
      }
     },
     {
      "google_id_token_https": {
       "audiences": [
        "AIzaSyAsnv2yeF6003txjfBVrZrlUe8jvfUJAtE"
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 "securityDefinitions": {
  "google_id_token_https": {
   "type": "oauth2",
   "authorizationUrl": "",
   "flow": "implicit",
   "x-google-issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
   "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
  },
  "api_key": {
   "type": "apiKey",
   "name": "key",
   "in": "query"
  },
  "google_id_token": {
   "type": "oauth2",
   "authorizationUrl": "",
   "flow": "implicit",
   "x-google-issuer": "accounts.google.com",
   "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
  }
 },
 "definitions": {
  "Status": {
   "enum": [
    "SUCCESS",
    "FAILURE"
   ]
  },
  "Response": {
   "properties": {
    "code": {
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
    },
    "data": {
     "$ref": "#/definitions/_any"
    },
    "message": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
     "$ref": "#/definitions/Status"
    }
   }
  },
  "_any": { }
 }
}
```

This configuration is then deployed using gcloud service-management deploy .

Comment: can you please post your configuration. how did you make your API required to use an API Key?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer All has been updated in the questions .

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: To repeat, how - in terms of code - are you forming and sending the request? I ask this so I can attempt to reproduce what you've seen.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the api key is validated when you have more than one arguments or more than one @Api annotated classes in your pom.xml and your web.xml

pom.xml

```
<arguments>
  <argument>get-swagger-doc</argument>
  <argument>--hostname=tita-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</argument>
   <argument>--war=target/tita-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>           
   <argument>com.rareatom.tita.services.TestApi</argument>                               
   <argument>com.rareatom.tita.services.SessionServices</argument>                     
                        </arguments>
```

And for your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rareatom.tita.services.TestApi,
        com.rareatom.tita.services.SessionServices</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how you make the request, and what the method handling the request looks like? You should anonymize anything you don't want to share. This would be very helpful in reproducing the behaviour, which I haven't observed to this point.